# C# Как получить букву только что подключённой флешки?

Tags: c#, .net

Копал в сторону `DriveInfo`, но сравнивать два массива — не слишком изящное решение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать технологию [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx).

Подключаете к проекту сборку System.Management.dll.

Пишете следующий код:

```
using System.Management;


var watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher();
var query = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 2");
watcher.Query = query;
watcher.EventArrived += Watcher_EventArrived;
watcher.Query = query;
watcher.Start();


private static void Watcher_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    var driveName = e.NewEvent.Properties["DriveName"].Value.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(driveName);
}
```

В событии получаем букву диска.

Объект `ManagementEventWatcher` является Disposable, поэтому крайне желательно после окончания работы с ним освободить ресурсы вызовом метода `Dispose` (или используйте `using`, если возможно).

Подробнее можно посмотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/620144/5045688).

Answer (score 5):

Могу предложить слушать оповещения от *Windows* - `WM_DEVICECHANGE`. Система присылает уведомления об изменении конфигурации аппаратуры среди устройств.

Конкретно Вам будут полезны:

`DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` - отправляется после вставки устройства или носителя. Программа получит это сообщение, когда устройство будет готово к использованию.

`DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE` - отправляется, когда система запрашивает разрешение на удаление устройства или носителя. Любое приложение может отклонить этот запрос и отменить удаление.

`DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE` - отправляется после того, как устройство было удалено. Когда ваша программа получает это событие, устройство больше не доступно.

Пример проекта на этом принципе:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18062/Detecting-USB-Drive-Removal-in-a-C-Program

Подробнее о `WM_DEVICECHANGE`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa363480(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Не худо было бы добавить немного кода в ответ. Ссылки умрут и более 50% информативности вашего ответа вместе с ними.